# Protect my htdocs folder with a password

Tags: php, apache, password-encryption

I did not find an answer to that question in the already asked one:
I have an ht docs folder on a machine and i would like to protect that folder with a password. the folder is not on my machine, its on another machine that i access remotely,

I tried 7 Zip but i want to avoid compressing the folder, because it contains source code that i need to access without compressing/decompressing

How can i protect that folder with a password without problems with running Apache
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would you be better changing the chown and permissions on the folder so that you require maybe root? 

Check chown and chmod for apache and see if this is a solution that would work for you.

Comment: Hello Tomos, thanks for the reply, I am working on a windows machine, I forgot to write that in my question

Comment: I think at that point maybe the security around accessing the machine is more important than a password on the file, there are still permissions for windows files though that would require an admin password etc before you could access the file.

Comment: The situation is that. Alot of people have the right to access the machine and i do not want to make the source code open for everyone accessing it.